# Removing elements from a List is causing for loop not to increment?

Tags: java, list, for-loop, dictionary, int

I am trying to *remove* Elements of a list if they have been included in a text file.

For example: If the String `"Person123`" was in the text file then the String `"Person123"` should be removed from the list.

Below is my current attempt. However I am getting an issue with iterating through "MyList", the `int` value does not seem to increment which is causing only one of the string elements to be removed, rather than two.

How can I fix this?

**Current Code:**

```
for (Map.Entry<Person, List<String>> entry : mapOfPeopleAndDescriptions.entrySet()) {
    List<String> textFileValues= readFromTextFile(filePath);
    List<String> myList = entry.getValue();

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {

                if(textFileValues.contains(myList.get(i)){

                    LOGGER.info("In loop- int: {}",i );
                    myList.remove(myList.get(i));

                }

                LOGGER.info("Out of loop- int: {}",i );

            }

    }
```

**Output I am getting:**

```
In loop- int: 0
Out of loop- int: 0
Out of loop- int: 1
Out of loop- int: 0
Out of loop- int: 1
Out of loop- int: 0
```

Comment: Iterate the list backwards. Also, use `myList.remove(i)`. Or use an `Iterator`.

Comment: @AndyTurner what do you mean?

Comment: `for (int i = myList.size(); i >= 0; i--) {`

Comment: That was a typo, changed now thanks

Comment: `myList.removeAll(textFileValues)` would be much easier than this loop.

Comment: @AndyTurner please add an answer to show this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop is unnecessary. Simply use `List.removeAll`:

```
myList.removeAll(textFileValues);
```

---

Note that if you are iterating by index and removing elements, you should do it in reverse:

```
for (int i = myList.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
  myList.remove(i);
}
```

Otherwise, you will need to change the value of `i` in the loop to avoid skipping the next element.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an iterator and then call the remove method : Iterator.remove().

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re).